# Test if UDP port is opened

Tags: c#, udp, timeout, host

So I have read other questions but I couldn't really understand the answers..
The question is simple. How can I test if e.g 25565 UDP port is opened on a public IP? My TCP port testing works, but UDP doesn't. This is the code I'm using:

```
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient();
        Socket sock = udpc.Client;
        sock.ReceiveTimeout = 30000;
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        try
        {
            sock.Connect(ip, port);
            udpc.Send(data, data.Length, ip, port);
            byte[] rec = udpc.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("UDP open.");
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UDP closed. (No reply in time.) " + e.Message);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UDP opened. Maybe the port is closed and you just entered too big number. You can view the exception here: " + e.Message);
        }
```

However, it's not working. I always get `UDP closed. (No reply in time.)` and the exception, which also says that it couldn't reply in time. I tried increasing the receive timeout to 60k ms, but it still didn't work. So, what's going on? In my imagination it sends the message to the host, and then it's waiting 60 seconds for a reply, but it doesn't get it. However, it should get a reply like ,,hey you im opened'' (well, as I said, imagination). So can someone explain how to do this, is this even possible and why is mine not working? Thanks!

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I did, but I still couldn't understand it, where is the part where it's open, or closed, etc..

Comment: UDP is connectionless. The `Connect()` method has no non-local effect for a UDP socket (such as establishing some kind of actual connection with a remote endpoint); it's for convenience of the local process only. And you can send a datagram to a remote endpoint, but unless you know the protocol in use and that protocol supports the remote endpoint responding to something you send, you have no guarantee that anything would be sent back to you. See marked duplicate for more details.